# Import the KML google Map file with Adobe Flash in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-maps

I've created a map with Map Engine. I saw that we can export it in KML format. Is there a way to import it in my AS3 project ?

For the moment, here's my code. It's displaying google Map and showing the city that I want. Know I'd like to import the KML file in order to have my layers.

```
import com.google.maps.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.Map;
import com.google.maps.MapEvent;
import com.google.maps.MapType;

var map:Map = new Map();
map.key = "AIzaSyCxiPVh482UPJ-cM6uBg6Fd88mTjxmQNV0";
map.sensor = "true";
map.setSize(new Point(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight));
map.addEventListener(MapEvent.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
this.addChild(map);

function onMapReady(event:Event):void {
  map.setCenter(new LatLng(-22.2758000,166.4580000), 14, MapType.NORMAL_MAP_TYPE);
}
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be looking for a KML parser.

There is one in the google maps utility library:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-flash/

In particular:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-flash/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fmaps%2Fextras%2Fxmlparsers%2Fkml

I wrote a utility to help load a kml file a long time ago, but depends on the version of maps you are using whether this will work:

http://distriqt.com/post/251

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry but I don't really understand how to proceed though... I've downloaded "GoogleMapsAPIUtilityLibrary_04262009.swc" file, put it in Components/Google. Should I download something else ?

Comment: Because if I do that, I've got an error (1172:  définition com.distriqt.gmaps.kml.utils was'nt found.

Comment: Do you have a "tutorial" for your kml parser ? I don't really understand how to use it. I'm wondering if it's not because I use Adobe Flash Pro and not Flex.

Comment: Hi, There is documentation and an example application on the code repository wiki: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-flash/wiki/Libraries. If you are looking to use the distriqt wrapper, there are tutorials on that second link I sent you.

Comment: The com.distriqt.gmaps.kml.utils is not in the google repository. You'll have to grab it off that second link. Cheers